# routing with get but security risk ? (laravel )

Tags: php, laravel

hi i was routing my html with post method and i got this error :

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException
```

i changed it to :

```
Route::get('/register', function()
{
    return View::make('register');

});
```

and it worked perfectly

but i post my input like this :

```
Route::get('/register', function()
{
    return View::make('register');

});

Route::post('/register', function()
{
    $user = new User;
    $user-> u_n = Input::get('u_n');
    $user-> u_fn = Input::get('u_fn');
    $user-> u_password = Input::get('u_password');
    $user-> u_email = Input::get('u_email');



    $user->save();


    if ($user->save())
    {
        return Redirect::intended('/register');
    }

});
```

i wanted to know if it is safe or not ?
how can i post and not get an error ?

Comment: You use **{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'url')) }}** or **<form action ..>** ?

Comment: {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'url')) }}